# Get the this object using eval in a gridview in asp

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, eval

I can't find any answer anywhere. I want to refer to the row object itself in an databinding expression in a gridview, like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" 
                   Text = '<%# GetPendingReason(Eval("this")) %>' />                                    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But it doesn't work because "this" doesn't refer to any attribute. Referencing individual attributes works fine, but how do you refer to the current row?

Comment: not sure its gonna work but try replacing Eval("this") to DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem)

Comment: Sorry, I think that you may replace by **(AnyTypeOfInterest)Container.DataItem** let me know if it helps!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refer to the current row you do that at codebehind using

`GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];`
at any of the GridView event.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to refer to the current row in the aspx code, not in the codebehind.

Comment: See answer below: Container.DataItem

Answer (score 10):

Simply use <%# Container.DataItem %>. Do not use Databinder.